# Creating tables and radio buttons dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, radio-button

I need to create an unknown number of the **same table** in asp.net page using c#.

This table has a **radio button list** and when its selected value changes, the table (that specific one) has to change and show something else.

The immediate problem I think of is when I assign the selected value changed event to each radio button list, I need to know which table to change.

What is the best practice of doing such a thing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a entity which contains you table and the corresponding radio-button-list and make a list of this entity in your main class